# Ubuntu 17.10 Runing Really Slow On Laptop

Tags: laptop, 17.10

just installed a fresh 17.10 ubuntu and its incredibly slow on my laptop and was just wondering if anyone could help
heres my specs

AMD® E2-7110 apu with amd radeon r2 graphics × 4

6GB Ram

500GB SSD

Many Thanks

edit heres my output

21.482s plymouth-quit-wait.service

```
     6.596s NetworkManager-wait-online.service

     2.300s dev-sda6.device

     1.627s grub-common.service

     1.422s apport.service

     1.398s speech-dispatcher.service

     1.317s udisks2.service

     1.313s fwupd.service

     1.207s accounts-daemon.service

     1.202s gpu-manager.service

     1.113s NetworkManager.service

     1.060s ModemManager.service

     1.055s snapd.service

      947ms thermald.service

      738ms systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service

      321ms systemd-udev-trigger.service

      282ms networking.service

      266ms systemd-rfkill.service

      257ms upower.service

      246ms systemd-resolved.service

      219ms apparmor.service

      210ms rsyslog.service

      201ms polkit.service lines 1-23...skipping...

    21.482s plymouth-quit-wait.service

     6.596s NetworkManager-wait-online.service

     2.300s dev-sda6.device

     1.627s grub-common.service

     1.422s apport.service

     1.398s speech-dispatcher.service

     1.317s udisks2.service

     1.313s fwupd.service

     1.207s accounts-daemon.service

     1.202s gpu-manager.service

     1.113s NetworkManager.service

     1.060s ModemManager.service

     1.055s snapd.service

      947ms thermald.service

      738ms systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service

      321ms systemd-udev-trigger.service

      282ms networking.service

      266ms systemd-rfkill.service

      257ms upower.service

      246ms systemd-resolved.service

      219ms apparmor.service

      210ms rsyslog.service

      201ms polkit.service

      191ms keyboard-setup.service

      166ms swapfile.swap

      149ms systemd-timesyncd.service

      145ms systemd-journald.service

      104ms packagekit.service

       76ms user@1000.service

       73ms gdm.service

       60ms dns-clean.service

       59ms avahi-daemon.service

       56ms systemd-logind.service

       55ms systemd-udevd.service

       41ms kerneloops.service

       35ms colord.service

       33ms systemd-modules-load.service

       31ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service

       25ms plymouth-start.service

       24ms systemd-journal-flush.service

       22ms wpa_supplicant.service
```

also its the side bar menu that the pointer drags and clicking show applicatons its laggy loading the icons and dragging windows around is laggy

Comment: Hard to know where to start. I guess with boot. Can you open a terminal with <Ctrl>+<Alt>+T and run `systemd-analyze blame` and then copy that output into your question? **NOTE:** You can page down the list and copy everything but the first screen should be enough, then press `q` to exit the screen.

Comment: Was Ubuntu 17.04 running fast? Or any other Ubuntu/Debian/Linux? What exactly do you mean by slow? 10min to boot? Does the mouse drag slowly across the screen like it's in mud, or does typing have a 2 second delay before letters show up? Is the `top`/`htop` CPU maxed out?

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem regarding lags and freezes, even with very low CPU and ram usage. Have you tried using X-org inspite of Wayland as a destkop enviroment? you can select Ubuntu (X.org) as a desktop at the login screen. I'm afraid there might me a bug affecting my specs, but after using X.org as my default display server, i'm experiencing no more lags and freezes.